# Sanskrit mantra of Sarasvati in agni purana to expand intelligence

Tags: mantras, sanskrit, saraswati, agni, agni-purana

Consider the following verses from Agni Purana regarding the goddess Sarasvati

> The chief mantra, that is (known as) Sarasvati (Goddess of learning),
> that which has the letters that have the directive at the end of the
> oblation (is) “For speech, deed, united to the side, white, and for
> the sake of the child is deemed to be the ship.”’ A person who repeats
> this collection of mantra a lakh times would become a wise man.

(or)

> The principal Mantra sacred to the lord of heaven, consists of the
> Vijas known as the Vak, Karma, etc., and ends with the one known as
> the Huta. The Mantra should be repeated a hundred thousand times,
> whereby the intellect of the repeater is sure to be expanded.
>
> [[1-2, Chapter 302: Description of different kinds of potential mantras and herbs, Agni Purana]](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.33602/page/n135/mode/2up)

The verses say that the mantra should be repeated one lakh times for the grace of Sarasvati. What is the mantra in actual Sanskrit text?

Answer (score 2):

In the Gita press translation, I found the mantra written before the verse.

[image]

> ऐं कुलजे ऐं सरस्वती स्वाहा।

I think this is the Mantra.